# Return array of hrefs

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I need Watir to return an array of hrefs.  These hrefs are all in the same div and they all have the same class.  My code to grab the first href on the page looks like this:

```
b.div(:class => 'products').link(:class => 'product_detail_url').href
```

But, after that I can't find out how to loop through all available hrefs in that div.

I honestly looked all over the place, but none of the solutions I found seemed to address my specific need.  Thanks for reading, hopefully someone has a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
b.div(:class => 'products').links(:class => 'product_detail_url').each do |link|
  puts link.href
end
```

Basically this iterates through a collection of links that have the specific class.

**Update:**

To collect all of the hrefs into an array, use the collect method:

```
link_arr = b.div(:class => 'products').links(:class => 'product_detail_url').collect{ |link| link.href }
```

Or break it into two lines for easier reading:

```
link_collection = b.div(:class => 'products').links(:class => 'product_detail_url')
link_arr = link_collection.collect{ |link| link.href }
```

Comment: That's it, thanks!  I had a crude solution running, but this is much much better.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can write it even shorter by using #map as a #collect's alias and short-block-syntax:

```
hrefs = b.div(:class => 'products').links(:class => 'product_detail_url').map(&:href)
```